# Get latest thread OR comment

Tags: mysql

I have a forum with a few categories, forums, threads and comments.
'f_cats', 'f_forums', 'f_threads' and 'f_comments'.

I want to show on the index page of the forums the latest activity in each forum. I have no problem getting the latest comment on each forum, but what if there's a non-commented thread which is newer than the last comments?

Is there a way to get the latest comment/thread id? And can the output contain the type of the post? (thread/comment)

Thanks!

Comment: Please share some sample data from these tables and your desired results since we don't really know what you mean by `forum`, `categories`, `threads`, and `comments`.

Comment: categories - id
forums - id, cid (the category it's referring to)
threads - id, fid (same)
comments - id, tid (same)